# where are the rules of suspension posted?

Tags: discussion

Where are the rules about suspension? Maybe they should be in FAQ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not exactly; the most common reasons are documented here:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

---

When users exhibit a pattern of either …

### No effort to learn and improve over time

- This user does not put reasonable effort into the questions they ask of the community.

  There is little or no evidence of this user learning over time, either in the topic itself or in the community norms on the site.

  This user intentionally spams the site with the same question or very similar questions, over and over.

  The user never gives anything back to the community, but only takes.

### Disruptive behavior

- Other users tend to react poorly to this user’s contributions, posting negative responses in kind and generally causing a commotion.

  There is a broad sense of community resentment over this user’s behavior, and they are frequently cited in discussion about the community.

  There is a dark storm cloud of [moderator flags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/) that seems to follow this user around wherever they go.

  The moderators get email complaints about this user’s behavior.

  This user makes overtly snide, rude, or hostile comments to their fellow users.

… these problem behaviors *have* to be dealt with. When they aren’t, it takes up excessive moderator time that could be used for something more productive — and, even worse, these behaviors begin to **actively turn people away from our community, stunting its growth and harming everyone.**

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're asking about the rules governing when a user can be suspended: there is only one, "don't be a jerk." This is intentionally vague. Suspensions are imposed at the discretion of the moderators. Generally they only occur after an official warning has been given but has not had the desired effect.

This is discussed on [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23366/suspension-reasons), and [this MSO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23661/what-is-the-point-of-a-30-day-account-suspension/23681#23681) (though I'm not saying we're obligated to use that exact sequence on this site).

Comment: Also, moderators' actions, like suspensions, are heavily logged to prevent any abuse.

Comment: Is it that simple? I noticed somebody with high reputation suddenly go to 1. Can he/she comment? edit? he/she was seen a few minutes ago according to profile. So I am asking what is the extent of the penalties, obviously not total exclusion. Just answering? plus commenting? Should it not be written somewhere: "if you are a jerk, as defined in faq, you are suspended for a number of days, at the discretion of moderators,  which means that.....

Comment: @anna: have a look at [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

Comment: OK, it is documented then. Maybe a link could be provided, and also what the penalties are is enumerated for people not familiar with the lingo.

Comment: We can refer people to this question when they ask about it.